# Problemas para criar Child no Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, realtime-database

Estou tentando add pratos no meu banco de dados do firebase porém estou tendo alguns problemas que até agora não sei o por que não funciona. e chega a dar este erro:

```
Process: meals.com.meals, PID: 1585
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.in
```

Para vocês verem o que eu estou fazendo vou postar também o código da activity e da classe prato.

```
public class CriarPrato extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner NomeRestaurante;
private EditText NomePrato1;
private EditText PrecoPrato1;
private Button GerarPrato;
private String IDrestaurante;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_criar_prato);


    NomeRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato);
    NomePrato1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomePrato);
    PrecoPrato1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrecoPrato);
    GerarPrato = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrato);

    Query queryPrato = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").orderByChild("localRestaurante");

    queryPrato.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //  final List<String> localRest = new ArrayList<String>();
            final List<String> NomeRestauranteList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Restaurante restaurante = data.getValue(Restaurante.class);
                //   localRest.add(restaurante.getLocalRestaurante().toString());
                NomeRestauranteList.add(restaurante.getNome().toString());
            }

            //LocalRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinerLocalPrato);
            // ArrayAdapter<String> areas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, localRest);
            // areas.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
            // LocalRestaurante.setAdapter(areas);

            NomeRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato);
            ArrayAdapter<String> NomeRestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, NomeRestauranteList);
            NomeRestAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
            NomeRestaurante.setAdapter(NomeRestAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Query query = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").orderByChild("nome").equalTo("McDonald's");

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                IDrestaurante = data.getKey();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    GerarPrato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Prato prato = new Prato();
            prato.setID(IDrestaurante);
            prato.setNomePrato(NomePrato1.getText().toString());
            prato.setPrecoPrato(PrecoPrato1.getText().toString());

            prato.Salvar(IDrestaurante);
        }
    });
}
```

Obs.: Eu sei que eu não estou ainda utilizando o spinner, tive alguns problemas para pegar o valor dele portanto coloquei na mão o valor, para fazer alguns testes.

```
public class Prato {

    private String ID;
    private String NomePrato;
    private String PrecoPrato;

    public Prato() {
    }

    public void Salvar(String key){
        DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia();
        reference.child("Restaurante").child(key).child("Cardapio").child(getID()).setValue(this);
    }
    @Exclude
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String key) {
        reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").child(key).child("Cardapio");
        this.ID = reference.push().getKey();
    }

    public String getNomePrato() {
        return NomePrato;
    }

    public void setNomePrato(String nomePrato) {
        NomePrato = nomePrato;
    }

    public String getPrecoPrato() {
        return PrecoPrato;
    }

    public void setPrecoPrato(String precoPrato) {
        PrecoPrato = precoPrato;
    }

    public DatabaseReference getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(DatabaseReference reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    private DatabaseReference reference;

}
```

Segue uma imagem da organização do banco de dados para melhor compreensão

[image: Eu quero adicionar em cada restaurante um nó chamado Cardápio e dentro deste nó Cardápio vou colocar meu produtos criando nós Com os id's e dentro deste id's vai ter as variáveis: nome do prato e valor no prato.]

Eu quero adicionar em cada restaurante um nó chamado Cardápio e dentro deste nó Cardápio vou colocar meu produtos criando nós Com os id's e dentro deste id's vai ter as variáveis: nome do prato e valor no prato.

Comment: Você pode nos mostrar um print do firebase RealtimeDatabase no console ? Assim fica um pouco mais fácil entendermos as estrutura dos nós filhos do seu banco

Comment: Concerteza vou editar e colocar

Comment: @EduardoRafaelMoraes fiz a alteração!!! Tks

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se eu entendi direito mas pelo que percebi da sua história, eu faria o banco com essa estrutura: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
....
no salvar da sua classe modelo ficaria assim:

```
public void Salvar(String key){
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia();
    reference.child("Restaurante")
          .child("Iguatemi")
          .child("cardapio")
          .child(nomeLoja)
          .push()
          .child(prato.getNomeRestaurante)//opcional, assim vc teria o nome do bobs seguido de nós com o nome do prato e o valor
          .setValue(this)
}
```

Isso, pensando que o Iguatemi é um shopping e tem algumas lojas nele, caso ele seja um restaurante você poderia eliminar o .child(nomeLoja), e para retornar os dados:

```
Query queryPrato = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").child(nomeRestaurante);
```

Acredito que assim fique mais facil de receber os nós no valueEventListener.

Comment: Eduardo eu entendi a sua resposta, é um boa ideia porem eu queria entender o por que o meu salvar não ta funcionando. No que eu vi o problema esta em salvar mesmo parece que ele estoura a quantidade mb que se pode passar para salvar. Porem não faz sentido pois são info TXT.